# Selecting (siblings) between two tags using XPath (in .NET)

Tags: .net, xpath

I'm using .NET 3.5 (C#) and the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to do some web scraping. Some fields that I need to extract are structured as paragraphs within which components are separated by line-break tags. I'd like to be able to select out the individual components between the line-breaks. Each component may be formed from multiple elements (i.e., it may not be just a single string).  Example:

```
<h3>Section title</h3>
<p>
  <b>Component A</b><br />
  Component B <i>includes</i> <strong>multiple elements</strong><br />
  Component C
</p>
```

I'd like to select out

```
<b>Component A</b>
```

Then:

```
Component B <i>includes</i> <strong>multiple elements</strong>
```

And then:

```
Component C
```

There may be more (`<br />` separated) components, too.

I can easily get the first component with:

```
p/br[1]/preceding-sibling::node()
```

I can also easily get the last component with:

```
p/br[2]/following-sibling::node()
```

But I haven't been able to work out how to extract the set of nodes /between/ two other tags (that is, nodes which are siblings but which precede node X and follow node Y).

The alternative is to scan through the elements manually – if that's the easiest way to do it then that's what I'll do, but XPath has so-far impressed me with its terseness, so I'm hoping there's a way of doing this, too.

#### Edit

Since I need to cope with the situation of having more than 3 components, it seems the answer will require multiple XPath calls at a minimum, so I shall proceed with a solution based on that (this is the answer I have 'accepted').  AakashM's answer has also helped me with my understanding of XPath, and so I have voted it up.

Thank you all for your help!  I hope I can return the favour one day.

#### Edit 2

The new answer provided by Dimitre Novatchev, with some tweaks, does indeed work correctly.

Solution:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    yield return para.SelectNodes(String.Format(
        "node()[not(self::br) and count(preceding-sibling::br) = {0}]", i));
    ++i;
} while (para.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("br[{0}]", i)) != null);
```

I should note that this loop is somewhat inefficient due to the repeated XPath queries to find out whether there are any more `br` tags.  In my case that inefficiency is not a problem, but be aware if you want to use this answer in some other situation (then again, if you did want to do this in a performance sensitive situation you should probably be scanning through manually anyway rather than using XPath).

And full test code (a modified version of the test code helpfully included by AakashM):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestXPath
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(@"
<x>
 <h3>Section title</h3>
 <p>
  <b>Component A</b><br />
  Component B <i>includes</i> multiple <strong>elements</strong><br />
  Component C
 </p>
</x>
            ");


            foreach (var nodes in SplitOnLineBreak(doc.SelectSingleNode("x/p")))
            {
                Dump(nodes);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<XmlNodeList> SplitOnLineBreak(XmlNode para)
        {
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                yield return para.SelectNodes(String.Format(
                    "node()[not(self::br) and count(preceding-sibling::br) = {0}]", i));
                ++i;
            } while (para.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("br[{0}]", i)) != null);
        }

        private static void Dump(XmlNodeList nodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("-->{0}<---", 
                                  node.OuterXml));                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the question, bit of a different query than most things you would want to accomplish in XPath, yet still very practical

Comment: I have provided a correct and practical solution for you :)

Comment: There is a better way to specify that <br/> elements should not be selected, see my edited answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This can easily be done with XPath 2.0 or with XPath 1.0 hosted by XSLT*.

**With XPath 1.0 hosted by .NET this can be achieved in several steps:**

1. Make the appropriate "p" node the current node.
2. Find the number of all **`<br />`** children of the current "p" node:

   **count(br)**
3. if N is the count, determined in step 2. for **$k** in `0` to `N` do:

   3.1 Find all nodes that are preceded by **$k** **`<br />`**  elements:

   **node()[not(self::br) and count(preceding::br) = $k]**

   3.2 For every such node found, get its string value

   3.3 Concatenate all string values obtained in step 3.2. *The result of this concatenation is all the text contained in the given paragraph*.

**Note**: In order to substitute what should stand for **`$k`** in step 3.1 it is necessary to dynamically construct this expression.

Answer (score 1):

If in your situation you always have exactly three 'pieces', separated by `br`s, you can use this XPath to get the middle 'piece':

```
//node()[preceding::br and following::br]
```

which uses the `preceding` and `following` axes to return all nodes between two `br`s, anywhere at all.

*edit* this is my test app (please excuse the `XmlDocument`, I am still working with .NET 2.0...)

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(@"
<x>
 <h3>Section title</h3>
 <p>
  <b>Component A</b><br />
  Component B <i>includes</i> <strong>multiple elements</strong><br />
  Component C
 </p>
</x>
            ");

            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(
                "//node()[preceding::br and following::br]");

            Dump(nodes);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Dump(XmlNodeList nodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("-->{0}<---", 
                                  node.OuterXml));                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
-->
      Component B <---
--><i>includes</i><---
-->includes<---
--><strong>multiple elements</strong><---
-->multiple elements<---
```

As you can see, you get an `XmlNodeList` with all the stuff between the `br`s.

The way I think about it is: This XPath returns any node anywhere, so long as *for that node*, the preceding axis contains a `br`, **and** the following axis contains a `br`.

Comment: A quick test suggests that this doesn't work (unless I've made some other stupid mistake).  My understanding was that when a node-set expression appears within a filter clause, it acts as a 'true' value if it contains any items, whereas for this to work it would instead have to perform a set-membership test (ie, act as 'true' only if the node being filtered is within the set returned by the node-set expression).  In this case, there are always some nodes before a br, and some nodes after, so it just selects everything. Please correct my understanding if I've got this wrong!

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking about it the wrong way round. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

How abouts:

```
p/*[not(local-name()='br')]
```

And then index that expression for whatever term you want

EDIT:

For your indexing issue:

```
p/*[not(local-name()='br') and position() < x and position() > y]
```

Comment: The first would be fine there weren't multiple elements between separators.  The second is more promising but requires me to know the absolute indexes of the separators when I build the XPath expression, which I'd have to find out in a separate scanning step of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the position() or maybe the count() methods.  Here's a *guess* that might *help* you get the right syntax.

```
p/*[position() > position(/p/br[1]) and position() < position(/p/br[2])]
```

EDIT: **Please read the comments before voting or commenting**.

Comment: This is promising, but the position() function (at least in the .NET implementation) does not take any arguments, which ruins it a bit.  Since position() finds the position of the context node, I wondered if there might be a syntax that will let me call position() in a different context.  I tried `../br[1]/position()` but this is also invalid &ndash; any other ideas along this line?

Comment: Personally, I would use C# code to do this work.  Getting the position of the two bounding elements in separate XPath calls would allow you to create a third XPath statement to retrieve the nodes you'd like to use.

Comment: This is an invalid XPath expression that doesn't even compile. The position() function has only zero arguments.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, but I did say it was a "guess" and that you should "read the comments" which already indicated that.